# Securing WCF services using ASP.NET Auth and a DomainService with Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have the basic ASP.NET authentication domain service running in my Silverlight app (the one that comes with the VS2010 Silverlight Business template).

How can I use the authentication that this grants to secure methods exposed by standard WCF services (also hosted in the same app in IIS)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is how you do it, the standard WCF service needs a couple of attributes, and you need to assign the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1
{
    public Service1()
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Registered Users")]
    public string DoSomeWork()
    {
        return "working";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is here: [Security for WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626373%28VS.91%29.aspx). What you're looking for is the [RequiresAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.requiresauthenticationattribute%28VS.91%29.aspx) attribute.

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
public Foo SomeMethodCall(object parameter1)
{
    return service.GetResult(parameter1)
}
```

Comment: I don't think you quite got my question. I have a domain service that provides the authentication, but an ordinary WCF operation that I want to secure. Once the user has been granted auth, they should then be able to use the ticket to call the standard WCF method (not a DomainService method).

Comment: Looks like I read that a bit different. Thanks for posting the info though. Looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Actually it's very easy, and *just works*, once you know how to do it :D